# How do I remove an element in a list, using forEach?

Tags: javascript, list, node.js

```
var people = ['alex','jason','matt'];

people.forEach(function(p){
    if(p.length > 4){
       //REMOVE THIS PERSON or pop it out of the list or whatever
    }
});

console.log(people) //should return ['alex','matt']
```

I want to remove an element out of the list, using this forEach loop.

Comment: I don't believe you're supposed to modify a list as you loop over it.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is (essentially) for problems; it is not a classroom.

Comment: I second Rafe and Tomalak's comments. To expand on what Rafe said: it's not normal practice to remove elements inside a for each loop (though I'm not sure how JavaScript handles it; maybe it'll work). You're (almost certainly) better off using a standard index-based for loop; I suggest looping backwards from the last element so that you can remove elements without having to adjust the index variable. Have a look at the [MDN Array doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for details on Array's methods.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You *shouldn't* modify the array you're looping on. You can produce a new one, though:

```
var newPeople = [];
people.forEach(function(p){
    if(p.length <= 4){
        newPeople.push(p);
    }
});
```

[Why you shouldn't modify array you're looping.](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/)

Comment: You can modify the array in the callback function provided to *forEach*, there is nothing in ES5 to say you can't.

Comment: @Hans Engel  - why `<=`? the OP is `< 4`. @Mrchief - the OP is `I want to remove an element out of the list` so I presume the intention is to modify the array (as do most Array methods).

Comment: @RobG, the OP was `> 4` - The complement of `>` is `<=`.

Answer (score 62):

Use the right tools for the right job. In this case:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].value === 5) {
        data.splice(i--, 1);
    }
}
```

or as @nnnnnn has suggested, loop backwards:

```
for (var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (data[i].value === 5) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

However, you should consider using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
data = data.filter(function (e) {
    return e.value !== 5;
});
```

or a utility function library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#remove) or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), which provide a function for removing elements from an array:

```
_.remove(data, function (e) {
    return e.value === 5;
});
```

The benefit of the latter two is that your code becomes more readable.

Comment: This is a neat solution that considers the issues of changing indecies!

Comment: `.filter` looks really nice

Comment: @Gajus FYI `.filter()` does not modify the array, it returns a new array. I've made an edit to reflect this. You might also want to update with shorter ES6 syntax- `data = data.filter(e => e.value !== 5);`

Comment: A backward for-loop is very efficient and is the most legible procedure that's suitable for dealing with a large dataset that you don't want to copy and clobber.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with `filter()`:

```
var people = ['alex','jason','matt'];

var shortPeople = people.filter(function(p){
    return p.length <= 4);
});

console.log(people);
console.log(shortPeople);
```

Answer (score 0):

ForEach, since ES5 can be used together with an index:

```
data.forEach(function (element, index) {
  if (element % 2 == 0) {
    data.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that this code snippet *doesn't actually work* -- if data is `[1,28,35,444,555,666,333,424,313,303,484,464,121,12,14,88,96,108,1224,777]` then this will turn it to `[1, 35, 555, 333, 313, 303, 464, 121, 14, 96, 1224, 777]`

Comment: This is true and it is easy to see why and so why forEach is not the correct approach for this task as @Gajus explained.

In your example, when we remove item with index 1 (value 28), the next element to be analyzed is index 2, which should be the value 35 but it is now the value 444, so 35 is skipped. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

```js
const filterByLength = (arr, len) => arr.filter(s => s.length <= len);

const people = ["jon", "alex", "jason", "matt"];
console.log(filterByLength(people, 4)); // ["jon", "alex", "matt"]
```