# How do I remove all items in arrayA from arrayB? in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This feels like a very basic javascript question but I have two arrays:

```
var arrayA =['content','I dont','want'];
var arrayB = ['content','want','puppies'];
```

desired result:

```
arrayB = ['puppies']
```

The items in the arrays are strings.

How do I do this?
(bonus points if the answer works in IE8+)

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps a good starting point is how do you delete something from an array?

Comment: Why  in arrayB's element is puppies here. I mean what kind of operation actually happens here.

Comment: what's supposed to happen to "I dont" here?

Comment: I understand how to remove one singular item from an array, was just hoping there was an easier way than looping through each item in an array and then checking index of that item in another array, then removing it if it's there. Just seemed like a painful way to do something I'd guess there was a built in function intended for.

Also the text in the strings was purely an example could have as easily used "foo" "bar". I was trying to boil this down to it's simplest form as the full thing I'm building is way more complex. I just forgot how to do this and couldn't find a useful answer googling

Answer (score 4):

You could filter `arrayB` and take only the elements, which are not included in `arrayA`

```js
var arrayA =['content','I dont','want'],
    arrayB = ['content','want','puppies'].filter(a => !arrayA.includes(a));

console.log(arrayB);
```

ES5

```js
var arrayA =['content','I dont','want'],
    arrayB = ['content','want','puppies'].filter(function (a) {
        return arrayA.indexOf(a) === -1;
    });

console.log(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 1):

For value types, the following should work:  (alas not in IE8 - as pointed out!)

```
function (arrayA, arrayB) {
  return arrayB.filter(function(b) {
    return arrayA.indexOf(b) == -1;
  });
}
```

Comment: That won't work in IE8. IE8 doesn't support filter or indexOf

Comment: @jas7457 I think I really knew that about `filter` deep down.  Although `indexOf()` support lacking in IE8 was genuinely news to me!  Learn something new everyday!

Comment: You can add indexOf to IE8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8

Answer (score 1):

> remove all items in arrayA from arrayB

The solution using `Array.prototype.forEach()` and `Array.prototype.splice()` functions:

```js
var arrayA =['content','I dont','want'],
    arrayB = ['content','want','puppies'];

arrayA.forEach(function (w) {
    var idx = arrayB.indexOf(w);
    ~idx && arrayB.splice(idx, 1);
});

console.log(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you down to IE9, but IE8 doesn't support indexOf. If you absolutely need IE8 support, you'll have to write a polyfill for indexOf.

```
var arrayA =['content','I dont','want'];
var arrayB = ['content','want','puppies'];

for(var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
    var index = arrayB.indexOf(arrayA[i]);
  if(index !== -1) {
    arrayB.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

console.log(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you to IE8

```
var arrayA =['content','I dont','want'];
var arrayB = ['content','want','puppies'];

for (var i = arrayB.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = arrayA.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arrayA[j] == arrayB[i]) {
            arrayB.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(arrayB);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayA.forEach((valueA)=>{
    let idx = (arrayB.findIndex( (valueB)=>valueB === valueA))
    if(idx != -1){
      arrayB.splice(idx,1)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

ES3 solution.

```js
var arrayA = ['content', 'I dont', 'want'];
var arrayB = ['content', 'want', 'puppies'];

for (var bIdx = arrayB.length - 1; bIdx >= 0; bIdx -= 1) {
  for (var aIdx = 0; aIdx < arrayA.length; aIdx += 1) {
    if (arrayB[bIdx] === arrayA[aIdx]) {
      arrayB.splice(bIdx, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrayB);
```

Notice that the outer loop (arrayB) runs in reverse as you will be removing items from the array with [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and it will therefore be re-indexed while you are iterating it, which would mean that you could miss some items if forward iterated.

See the following for some further examples and explanations.

[How to remove element from array in forEach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812930/how-to-remove-element-from-array-in-foreach-loop/24813338#24813338)

You can happily use functional methods on IE8 (as long as you are not using sparse arrays) provided you load the appropriate shims for the methods that you use.

https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

https://github.com/es-shims/es6-shim

https://github.com/es-shims/es7-shim

If it is not essential that you mutate the original array, then you can use the [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) concept and replace the old array with a new one.

```js
var arrayA = ['content', 'I dont', 'want'];
var arrayB = ['content', 'want', 'puppies'];

var result = [];
for (var bIdx = 0; bIdx < arrayB.length; bIdx += 1) {
  var itemB = arrayB[bIdx];
  var found = false;
  for (var aIdx = 0; aIdx < arrayA.length; aIdx += 1) {
    if (itemB === arrayA[aIdx]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found !== true) {
    result.push(itemB);
  }
}
arrayB = result;

console.log(arrayB);
```

Notice that we can now forward iterate both arrays as they are not being mutated and no re-indexing is occuring.