# Item is not defined in a for each loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812930/how-to-remove-element-from-array-in-foreach-loop) but when doing:

```
let users = [{name: 'john', address: '10 king street'}, ....];

users.forEach(item, index, object => {
```

I get the error:

```
item is not defined
```

I need this so I can:

```
object.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: your syntax seems wrong. Try `users.forEach((item, index, object) => {`

Comment: You're using `foreach` incorrectly. It's first argument is a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When passing multiple parameters to an arrow function, enclose them in parentheses:

```
users.forEach((item, index, object) => { ... }
```

(See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax)

For example, to remove all users named "john," do this:

```
users.forEach((item, index, object) => {
  if(item.name == 'john') {
    object.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
let users = [
  {name: 'john', address: '10 king street'},
  {name: 'mary', address: '10 queen street'},
  {name: 'john', address: '10 prince street'},
  {name: 'hank', address: '10 duke street'}
];

users.forEach((item, index, object) => {
  if(item.name == 'john') {
    object.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between item and object?

Comment: @panthro read the docs, item is the current iteration's item, object is the entire array

Answer (score 1):

you need to put all the params into parenthesis like :

```
users.forEach((item, index, object) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the parameters to the arrow function in parentheses.

```
users.forEach(item, index, object => { /* ... */ })
```

Doing this means you pass to the function `item`, `index`, and an arrow function with a single param `object`(parentheses not needed with a single param).
Change to this:

```
users.forEach((item, index, object) => { /* ... */ })
```

This will pass an arrow function with 3 params: `item` is the current item, `index` - the index, `object` - the object `forEach` was called on - in this case `users`.