# Javascript: delete object from array based on value inside object

Tags: javascript

I have built an array-object structure as below

```
nestedArray = [ { source : "a" , target : "b", table : "ab" }, 
{ source : "c" , target : "d", table : "cd" }, 
{ source : "a" , target : "d", table : "cd" }, 
{ source : "a" , target : "f", table : "cd" }];
```

And I wrote below code to remove all nested objects where `source` is `a`.

```js
nestedArray.forEach(function(element) {
  if(element.source == "a") {
    nestedArray.splice(nestedArray.indexOf(element), 1) ;
  }
});
```

But when I try printing the array after above code, I can still see an object with `source` as `a`.

```js
> > nestedArray 
[ { source: 'c', target: 'd', table: 'cd' },  
 { source: 'a', target: 'f', table: 'cd' } ]
> >
```

Am I missing anything here ? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `filter()` instead of `forEach()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why my code is not working ?

With `splice` you're mutating original array and which changes length of array you're looping on and in turn you skip some indexes, i.e.

- first match is at index `0` so when you splice the remaining elements indexes it reduces by `1` so, but as you're looping already on the same array so `index` value of loop is set to `1` after iteration
- Now element at `1` is `{source: 'a'...}` not `{source: c}` so now when we splice again the index reduces by `1` and `index` value of loop is set to `2` after iteration
- so now on index `2`, but there's no value at that particular index

You can simply use filter

```js
let nestedArray = [ { source : "a" , target : "b", table : "ab" }, 
{ source : "c" , target : "d", table : "cd" }, 
{ source : "a" , target : "d", table : "cd" }, 
{ source : "a" , target : "f", table : "cd" }];

let op = nestedArray.filter(({source})=> source !== 'a')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: @TylerRoper i have added, but trying to form a better explanation for it

Comment: No worries, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a `forEach` and `slice` is the list shrinks but the index keeps going and so elements are skipped. Instead I'd recommend `filter`

```js
nestedArray = [ { source : "a" , target : "b", table : "ab" }, 
{ source : "c" , target : "d", table : "cd" }, 
{ source : "a" , target : "d", table : "cd" }, 
{ source : "a" , target : "f", table : "cd" }];

const result = nestedArray.filter(o => o.source !=='a');

console.log(result);
```

If a `forEach` is required instead of `filter` make a new list, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6950264/3462319)